# retrieve event registration link with api v4

Tags: civievent, urls, apiv4

I'm retrieving event details for a plugin, and thanks to some help here, I am now using the correct API to access the information. However, I am currently using the following to generate a registration link for an event, but I'd like to do the same using APIv4. I've searched the API reference and the API Explorer, with no luck.

```
        $id = $event['id'];
        $reglink = CRM_Utils_System::url( 'civicrm/event/register', "reset=1&id=$id" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any option in the API to generate registration link, the code you are using should create the correct link

```
 $id = $event['id'];
 $reglink = CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/event/register', "reset=1&id={$id}");
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I assumed this utility would be replaced by some call to the API, but if this still valid, I will stick with it. Thank you.